# Is there a good C++ tool for parsing a decimal?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

I have a place in my code where I have an element `iter` of type `std::string::const_iterator` and if `*iter` is the beginning of a decimal (i.e. the beginning of a string of the form `-00.01`, `.60`, `12319.1`, `99`, etc.) then I want to advance `iter` until it has passed through the decimal string and I want to store the decimal string.

For a concrete setup of the scenario:

```
for (std::string::const_iterator iter(str.begin()), offend(str.end()); iter != offend; ++iter)
{
    if (iter == '(')
    {
       //... blah blah blah
    }
    else if (iter is the beginning of a decimal representation)
    {
       parse the decimal representation, store it in a string, advance iter to the character at the end of the decimal representation (or to offend -- whichever comes first)
    }
    else if (some other condition involving iter)
    {
       // ... blah blah blah
    } 
    //...
}
```

Is there a `C++` tool that I can exploit for this scenario?

Comment: Search StackOverflow for "c++ read file array double".

Comment: Possible duplicate**s**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885481/c-read-from-a-text-file-lines-of-double, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337972/read-doubles-out-of-txt-file-into-double-array-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I am understanding your question right, you can use [std::stod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/) which will convert the captured string to a double. If you just want to keep the decimal in string format and hence extract it from a different string, you can use [string::substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) for extraction.